# New column based on comparison with values from predecessor row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
  Doc          Date      Q   F
30040771    2020-04-22  220  1     
30040771    2020-04-22  88   0     
30040771    2020-04-22  88   0
30040771    2020-04-22  100  0
```

I want to add a new column based on a comparison of each row and it's predecessor.
I have a working solution using shift(-1) on columns Doc, Date and Q and then comparing values in Doc, Date and Q with the values in the shifted columns.
Comparison is the following:

```
df["New_Col"] = (df["F"] ==1) & (df["Doc"] == df["Doc_Shift"]) & (df["Date"] == df["Date_Shift"]) & (df["Q"] != df["Q_Shift"])
```

Resulting in:

```
  Doc          Date      Q   Doc_Shift  Date_Shift  Q_Shift  F   New_Col
30040771    2020-04-22  220  30040771   2020-04-22     88    1     1
30040771    2020-04-22  88   30040771   2020-04-22     88    0     0
30040771    2020-04-22  88   30040771   2020-04-22     100   0     0
30040771    2020-04-22  100  30040771   2020-04-22     88    0     0
```

My solution works but it's ugly.
The original df has multiple docs and dates in it.
How can I solve that problem more efficient & pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Doc': {0: 30040771, 1: 30040771, 2: 30040771, 3: 30040771},
   ...:  'Date': {0: '2020-04-22', 1: '2020-04-22', 2: '2020-04-22', 3: '2020-04-22'},
   ...:  'Q': {0: 220, 1: 88, 2: 88, 3: 100},
   ...:  'Doc_Shift': {0: 30040771, 1: 30040771, 2: 30040771, 3: 30040771},
   ...:  'Date_Shift': {0: '2020-04-22',
   ...:   1: '2020-04-22',
   ...:   2: '2020-04-22',
   ...:   3: '2020-04-22'},
   ...:  'Q_Shift': {0: 88, 1: 88, 2: 100, 3: 88},
   ...:  'F': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}})
   ...: df
Out[2]: 
        Doc        Date    Q  Doc_Shift  Date_Shift  Q_Shift  F
0  30040771  2020-04-22  220   30040771  2020-04-22       88  1
1  30040771  2020-04-22   88   30040771  2020-04-22       88  0
2  30040771  2020-04-22   88   30040771  2020-04-22      100  0
3  30040771  2020-04-22  100   30040771  2020-04-22       88  0

In [3]: df['New_Col'] = ((df.F == 1) & df.filter(regex="Doc").nunique(axis=1) & df.filter(regex="Date").nunique(axis=1)  & (df.filter(regex="Q").n
   ...: unique(axis=1) != 1)).astype(int)
   ...: df
Out[3]: 
        Doc        Date    Q  Doc_Shift  Date_Shift  Q_Shift  F  New_Col
0  30040771  2020-04-22  220   30040771  2020-04-22       88  1        1
1  30040771  2020-04-22   88   30040771  2020-04-22       88  0        0
2  30040771  2020-04-22   88   30040771  2020-04-22      100  0        0
3  30040771  2020-04-22  100   30040771  2020-04-22       88  0        0
```